# I am only seeing real-time data in my Google Analytics (Universal Analytics) hits

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am not seeing any stored data in the audience overview, but only real-time data. Furthermore, I am not getting any dimension hits, even though I set these values in Admin>Custom Definitions>Custom Dimensions. Is there something silly I am missing?

Here's my code. I am running `plugin_code (state)` every time the history state changes.

```
var ga = undefined
 function plugin_code (state) {
  if (typeof ga == "undefined") {
   window.GoogleAnalyticsObject = "ga"
   if (typeof window.ga == "undefined") {
    ga = window.ga = function () {
     window.ga.q = window.ga.q || []
     window.ga.q.push (arguments)
    }   
    window.ga.l = 1 * new Date ()
    var ga_script_tag    = document.createElement("script")
    var first_script_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
    ga_script_tag.async = 1
    ga_script_tag.src   = "//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"
    first_script_tag.parentNode.insertBefore (ga_script_tag, first_script_tag)
   }
  }
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto')
  state.gid = 1 // debug.
  if (state.gid) ga('set', 'dimension1', state.gid)
  if (state.a)   ga('set', 'dimension2', state.a)
  ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': state.page, 'title': state.page})
 }
```

Comment: What did you set your dimension scopes to be? Just curious.

Comment: It is set to "hit". I think I just needed to wait for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Data in Standard Reporting can take up to 24 hours to display.

> According to Google, site statistics update every 24 hours, but the company doesn't specifically state how long it takes to update other information that may be associated with your Google Analytics account. For example, you may also be using Google's AdWords to purchase text-based advertising on other sites. Professionals such as Internet marketing consultant Talal Melhem suggest that traffic data updates every three to four hours, AdWords can take up to 24 hours and E-commerce data in your Google Analytics dashboard lags further behind at up to 72 hours. -- Source: [How Frequently Does Google Analytics Update?](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/frequently-google-analytics-update-33562.html)

Also, check your [Profile Filters](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033162) to make sure you're not excluding traffic.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Apparently the basic data is being recorded but I think I don't get any dimension data. I think it's because of the way the website is set up. (as a single-page web-app). Is there some way to make sure all directories and sub-directories are actually recorded for a specific URL? (assuming that we have the code I pasted above)

Comment: Apparently I just needed to set the default URL back to the base site, instead of the entry page...